# Почему не запускается проект?

Tags: c#, wpf

Вызов происходит так (WPF):

```
REST0.Program.Connect();
```

В проект добавлено консольное приложение

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace REST0
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
        public static void Connect()
        {

        }

    }
}
```

> Возникли ошибки сборки

В ссылках подсвечивается значок предупреждения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при этом пусто в списке ошибок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу значка - это не **Error** (Ошибка), а **Warning** (Предупреждение).Чтобы его увидеть - достаточно открыть окно со списком ошибок и нажать вкладку отображения предупреждений вот тут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И как Вы уже правильно заметили - всего лишь несовпадение версий. Решается просто: зайти в свойства проекта, перейти на вкладку <kbd>Application</kbd> (В русифицированной *VS* название вкладки будет <kbd>Приложение</kbd>) и найти там свойство <kbd>Target Framework</kbd>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для обоих проектов выставить одинаковую версию фреймворка и предупреждение пропадет. После этого проект запустится. Хотел написать комментарий, но вот ответ слишком общий - решил написать более развернутую версию, чтобы это было полезно для других.

Answer (score 2):

Версия фреймворка не совпадала в проектах.